# IMagick delegate failed "ffmpeg" While Converting jpg stream to mp4

Tags: video, ffmpeg, imagemagick

Here is the command I am using,

```
$ convert -antialias -delay 1/2 Images/*.jpg test.mp4

Output: convert: delegate failed `"ffmpeg" -v -1 -i "%F%%d.jpg" "%u.%m" 2> "%Z"' @ error/delegate.c/InvokeDelegate/1310.
```

I have tried installing ffmpeg first and then Installing imagemagick.
But the funny thing is when I use the same command to convert the images stream to mpeg it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that, mpeg does not require the height and width of image to be in even number, but mp4 requires it.
So I Fixed the problem by using

```
- resize "even x even!"
```

e.g.

```
$ convert -antialias -delay 1/2 Images/*.jpg -resize "640x480!" test.mp4
```